# How to combine this jquery line

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html

```
<select class="form-control state" name="state" placeholder="State">
    <option value="" selected>- Select State -</option>
</select>
```

and this is my working jquery and this will execute when I change on the `country` `<select>`

```
$modal.find(".state").children().remove();
$modal.find(".state").append($('<option>', {
    value: "",
    text: "- Select State -",
}));
```

and this is my test so far on how to make this a one line jquery to make it cleaner but it didn't work.

```
$modal.find(".state").children().remove().parent().append($('<option>', {
    value: "",
    text: "- Select State -",
}));
```

Comment: If you use .remove, other methods after remove won't work

Comment: .remove() will remove your element and then you can't access the parent of ".state". It won't work. You need to use them seperately only.

Comment: so no need to change my code already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$modal.find(".state").html("<span> Content Here </span>");
```

I think you're complicating things.

Answer (score 0):

Remove parent from the code.

```
$modal.find(".state").children().remove().append($('<option>', {
    value: "",
    text: "- Select State -",
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

```
var $states = $modal.find(".state"); /* cache element for performance */
$states.children().remove();
$states.append($('<option>', {
    value: "",
    text: "- Select State -",
}));
```

One more way you can go with instead of removing children and then adding children just update html of select:

```
$modal.find(".state").html($('<option>', {
    value: "",
    text: "- Select State -",
})); /* this will over-right content of select element  */
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$modal.find(".state").html('<option value="" selected>- Select State -</option>');
```

Or

```
$modal.find("select[name=state]").html('<option value="" selected>- Select State -</option>');
```